# Terminology - note or tone?

Tags: theory, terminology

For the 2,000th theory question! The leading note is often called the leading *tone*, albeit being one *semitone* below the root note. Why has it been called thus? It can't be right!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. You're asking whether *note* and *tone* are sometimes synonyms?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - simply it's a semitone leading to the root, not a tone.

Comment: leadingsemitone just doesn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: @b3ko - suppose it depends what key you're in...

Comment: i use the words tone and note interchangeable (though i would rarely say tone unless it was a pure sine wave for example) and call semitones and tones, halfsteps and whole steps. So maybe this is just a cultural clash because for me the leading tone is just that special note halfstep below the tonic. if you are the type to call them semitones and tones this could be confusing i guess.

Comment: A "semitone" can only mean an *interval,* never a *pitch*. The word "tone" has both meanings - either "a pitch", or "an interval of two semitones." (Of course "tone" in English can also mean "timbre" - language is messy.)

Comment: @tim are you British? here in the states i think it is rare to use the term semitone to describe a half step. just curious.

Comment: Interesting question, should the seventh  degree be referred to as a tone or a semi-tone. It has a whole tone interval between the sixth and the seventh degree, but only a semitone between the seventh and the octave. I think I'll have to adjust my vocabulary and use the term 'note' instead of tone. It seems to be a little more accurate description to me.

Comment: @b3ko - well spotted! English, if pushed! But, yes, maybe it's just an English language quirk. But leading note seems more apposite.

Comment: @skinnypeacock it is a note when heard by itself. in context of the key your ear expects it to resolve to the tonic. i think that is all the term means. it is a leading note. has nothing to do with the interval between it and any other note.

Comment: @tim i agree "leading note" seems more precise and less confusing especially for those that use the terms semitone and tone to mean step and half step.

Comment: @skinnypeacock - 'should the seventh degree be referred to as a tone or a semitone in itself wouldn't make sense. Neither does the use of 'tone' for a particular note (to me). In fact, why use 'tone' at all in a situation like this?

Comment: @Tim- 'In fact, why use "tone" at all in a situation like this?  For the life of me, I can't think of a good reason. Only goes to show, people don't always have good reasons for their word choices.

Comment: tone has multiple meanings.  It can refer to a specific note, a harmonic in a series, or the timbre of an instrument, or even used in an other sense, e.g. "I don't like the tone of your voice".  Language is that way sometimes.

Comment: @User 50691 - my point. But when there are alternatives, why use an ambiguous one?

Answer (score 3):

To summarize what I got out of comments above:

Tone and Note are sometimes used interchangeably, even though they probably shouldn't be.

In some parts people tend to say Tone and SemiTone (British English) where in other parts they will say Whole Step or Half Step (US English).

The phrase "leading tone" is probably not phrased in the best way since it is a half step (or semi tone) below the tonic.

To be 100% clear one can use the phrase "Leading *Note*".  Or just realize that language is full of inconsistencies and just remember that the leading tone is just a name and may not fit the technical definition of Tone in all contexts.

Comment: So, why does the term leading *Tone* keep getting used, when it's patently obviously misleading?

Comment: @tim google brings back the first definition for "tone" as "a musical or vocal sound with reference to its pitch, quality, and strength". So it's a tone or pitch that leads to the tonic. Maybe you're overthinking this? Just call it the subtonic. ??

Comment: But the subtonic is usually the flattened seventh scale degree, isn't it?

Comment: @dekkadeci google says "the note below the tonic, the seventh note of the diatonic scale of any key."

Comment: @b3ko, the only place I remember reading the word "subtonic" is in a minor-key context. There, it meant the flattened seventh scale degree, not the leading tone.

Comment: No use trying to get the "right" answer here.  Because "tone" and "note" can both mean "musical sound", and because (at least in my opinion) a whole tone below the tonic (say, F to G) can also function as a leading tone in, say, Mixolydian or Dorian, then the confusion cannot be avoided, except by specifying actual intervals.  "Note" and "tone" also use the same letters.  Luckily, in context, the meaning is usually clear.

Answer (score 1):

OP is correct; the "leading tone" is a semitone below the tonic. In this case, "tone" referst to a note in meaning. Since the distance of a half-step is one-half of a tone, it is called a semitone. **The two meanings of tone as either a note or as a specific interval** are not the same, and in this case "leading tone" is referring to a note.

---

"Leading tone" would be a synonym of "leading note" if theorists were actually smart, but they like to make people's lives hard sometimes, so they gave **the same word two meanings.**